# Reporting variable importance results using cforest

Tags: r, random-forest, reporting, party

I have a large data set of odour samples. I used cforest and varimp to determine the most important variables (ie chemical compounds) in identifying sex.
How do I report this in a paper? Do I need to report OOB error? If so, how do I retrieve it in the party package; cforest?